# how to get Repeated character from String and how many times it repeated

Tags: java

Hello I'm new in programming, and sorry for my English.
So question is, for example: we have string "cabbaa"
and I should get `1c1a2b2a`

which means: 1 times'c', 1 times'a', 2 times'b', 2 times'a'

I could write code which gets `1c3a2b`:

```
public class test {

    static int i,j,k,c=0,w;
    static char m;  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frequencycount("cabbaa");
    }


    static void frequencycount(String s)

    {

        char[] z=new char[s.length()];
        for(w=0;w<s.length();w++)
        z[w]=s.charAt(w);
        for(i=0;i<w;i++)
        {
            char ch=z[i];
            for(j=i+1;j<w;j++)
            {
                if(z[j]==ch)
                {
                    for(k=j;k<(w-1);k++)
                    z[k]=z[k+1];
                    w--;
                    j=i;
                }
            }
        }

        int[] t=new int[w];
        for(i=0;i<w;i++)
        {
            for(j=0,c=0;j<s.length();j++)
            {
                if(z[i]==s.charAt(j))
                c++;
            }
            t[i]=c ;
            System.out.print(c+""+z[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

in this code I guess I compared all characters overall from string and got `1c3a2b`, but I should get `1c1a2b2a`.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frequencycount("cabbaa");
    }   

    static void frequencycount(String s) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        Character previousCharacter = null;
        int counter = -1; 

        for (Character c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (c.equals(previousCharacter)) {
                counter++;
            } else {
                if (previousCharacter != null) {
                    output.append(counter);
                    output.append(previousCharacter);
                }
                counter = 1;
                previousCharacter = c;
            }
        }

        if (previousCharacter != null) {
            output.append(counter);
            output.append(previousCharacter);
        }

        System.out.println("Res: " + output);
    }   
}
```

Comment: If you're curious how it works then we iterate over each character in string. If this character is the same as previous one we increment counter, otherwise we print counter and previous character. Beware of special conditions which are beginning (when we don't have previous character) and end when we need to print last character.

Comment: Thank you very much you saved my day :)